# Loop through to Find Elements Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to loop through this container that is repeated multiple times on one page and print the time inside the span tag:

```
<div testid="Item-Content">
<div></div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>5:00pm</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Order = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@testid="Item-Content"]')
for Times in Order:
    Time = Times.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span')

    print(Time.text)
```

Errors with selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Comment: the structure of other times are same ? I mean all those divs and span.

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code.It should print the value.

```
Order =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@testid='Item-Content']")
for times in Order:
    print(times.find_element_by_xpath("//span").text)
```

OR you can also use WebdriverWait to handle the same.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Order=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@testid='Item-Content']")))
for times in Order:
   print(times.find_element_by_xpath("//span").text)
```

Comment: Thanks KunduK. It just printed several blank lines in a row when I ran both of those.

Comment: based on your div tag it is printing value here

Comment: can i have your full html ?

Comment: It's going to very hard to send that over in a comment. It's tons of nested divs with dynamic classes and IDs.

Comment: Is your url public?

Comment: Orders page inside Shopify that's password protected.

Comment: Try changing to this line. `print(times.find_element_by_xpath("//span").get_attribute('textContent'))`

Comment: @supputuri : the html which has provided its perfectly working with text not required.`get_attribute('textContent')`.The problem he is having the structrue he posted not always same and he can't share url to check which is protected.